# How to avoid IE Navigation error which says the RPC server is unavailable?

Tags: vb.net

I have a service which is installed on my server. It suddenly stops with the following error log:

```
  The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.VBBinder.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Type objType, IReflect objIReflect, Object target, Object[] args, String[] namedParameters)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.InternalLateCall(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateCall(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
   at vbIranStock.VBNetLib.vbScript4.Parsing(Object& objIE, Object& MainHTML, String[]& logid, String& logpath, String& Servicepath, Boolean& doPrint) in vbScript4.vb:line 119
   at vbIranStock.VBNetLib.vbScript4.VbsRun4(Boolean doPrint) in vbScript4.vb:line 50
   at WindowsServiceVB.Service1.MyProgram() in Service1.vb:line 106
   at WindowsServiceVB.Service1.ScheduleService() in Service1.vb:line 73
```

When I refer to the specified Visual Basic code line, I see following codes:

```
119:  objIE.Navigate("https://www.example.ir" + lblUrl)
```

I checked following RPC related services which all are running and are not stopped:

```
Remote Process Call
Remote Process Call Locator
DeCom Server Process Launcher
RPC Endpoint Mapper
Remote Access Connection Manager
Remote Access Auto Connection Manager
Remote Registry
```

Besides I checked firewall and added inbound and outbound rules to allow my service connection.
But again I have this error. Please help me to stop getting the error.

Comment: Is the service running under an account which can use the RPC server? The name `objIE` makes me wonder if it is trying to use a WebBrowser control - if so, could it be re-written to avoid that, e.g. use a WebClient and some API on the web server.

Comment: I use a "InternetExplorer.Application"  object to navigate to the url. what is the difference between "WebBrowser" control and "WebClient"? what is wrong with IE application?

Comment: A WebBrowser has all the parsing and rendering associated with it, whereas a WebClient simply fetches data from the server. The `vbIranStock` makes me wonder if it is scraping web pages - it is better to get the data in some format like JSON or XML through an API as it takes less processing for everyone, and if the website changes its layout then your program doesn't need to be re-written.